# Emoji not encoding properly

Tags: php, json, facebook

I am building a Facebook messenger bot, I am trying to display an emoji like so

```
 $data =json_encode([
'speech' => "\xF0\x9F\x98\x84",
'displayText' => "test",
'source' => "source"
]);

$output = json_decode($data);
echo ' '.$output->speech;
```

This works on my local script but when I try to display the emoji on the Facebook messenger, I get this error:

"invalid character 'ð' looking for beginning of value

Comment: Did you try special html characters? Please post the code you use to dispaly the "emoji`

Comment: Accept my answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Using an emoji shortform works. This [website](http://emojicodes.com/) contains a list of shortforms that will work on the facebook messenger platform as well as facebook website

```
$data =json_encode([
'speech' => ">:(",
'displayText' => "test",
'source' => "source"
]);

$output = json_decode($data);
echo ' '.$output->speech;
```

Whereas, sending either the unicode or Hex representation of the emoji doesn't seem to work.